# Pass Variables between web apps javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I am currently programming a take away app in a program called AppLab.(uses Javascript)
The Html code in AppLab is not possible to modify and therefore I had to use an external Web app, where the checkout is possible to make.(I cannot integrate paypal buttons in AppLab)
The user gets directed to the web app after clicking on a button.
To program the Web app I use google apps script.
Now my question: How do I get the amount he has to pay (declared as variable in AppLab) to the google apps sript?

Comment: The whole checkout happens in the web app, not just the payment, right?

Comment: yes, the whole checkout.

Comment: Then just use an URL parameter: `web.app.example/checkout?shoppingcart=12345`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable from AppLab to Google Apps Script via post and use the `doPost(e)` function in GAS to get the purchase data.

Or you can pass the purchase ID in the URL to the webApp, use the `doget(e)` function in GAS to get the ID and then use the `fetch()` function to exchage data with AppLab to get the amount for that purchase ID.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I would like to use the first method. But could you help me with the post method in AppLap, because it always says some kind of error message.

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in AppLab. Maybe you should ask that in another question.